Use BeEquivalentTo between types whose property names use different naming conventions
I have a pair of DTOs which were defined using different naming conventions, one using PascalCase while the other uses camelCase.
When I run a verification of result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(camelCase, PascalCase), I get the following failure:
Expectation has property result.camelCaseProperty that the other object does not have.

I've been circumventing this problem by configuring checks such as:
       result.Should().BeEquivalentTo(camelCase, options => options
           .WithMapping("someVariable", "SomeVariable"));

However, this ends up being too verbose.
Does FluentValidation offer any way to configure mapping changes reflecting naming conventions?
